# RuntimeException ZygoteInit.main crash

Tags: android, runtimeexception

My game in play store with more than Million active users is facing lots of crashes seems to be caused by the android system itself not something specific in my game or code.
I cannot find out how to get rid of those crashes.

**Exception StackTrace is:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2721)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2782)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4607)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1529)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6228)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

As you can see, the full stacktrace doesn't contain any classes other than the android system or java classes.

So what do you think?

Can that be caused by something wrong in my code or not ?

And how can I prevent such crashes ?

Thanks

Comment: This is not the **full** logcat. You miss (at least) the `Caused by ...` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the full Play Console Crash StackTrace, nothing more. leads me to a situation which makes me unable to find out what is the root cause of the issue